# How overload C++ functions in Lua using generic function template

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

I have C++ overloaded functions and want to use it in Lua. I am trying to make a generic C function (called by Lua) to call them depending of arguments.
I have little experience in modern C++ and have no ideia if this is really possible.

This is a pseudocode:

```
void foo(int value){
...
}

void foo(std::string value){
...
}


template<Ret, Func1, Func2, ...>
Ret overload(lua_State *L){
    if (lua_tointeger(L, 1))
        Func1(lua_tointeger(L, 1));

    if (lua_tostring(L, 1))
        Func2(lua_tostring(L, 1));
}
```

Using LuaBridge to bind:

```
luabridge::getGlobalNamespace (L)
  .beginNamespace ("test")
    .addFunction ("foo", overload<(void (*)(int))&foo, (void (*)(std::string))&foo>)
  .endNamespace ();
```

Is this possible? Can anyone help me?

Comment: C ? Do you mean C++ ?

Comment: "I have C overloaded functions" - I doubt that. C does not support function overloading.

Comment: C do not have function overloading - C++ has introduced that feature. This is why to export C++ functions and to be compatible how C functions are exported name mangling has been introduced.

Comment: It's C++, I am sorry.

Comment: In theory, this is possible. Lua can distinguish the type of an argument between a string and a number. I don't know how to do that using LuaBridge. With a manual binding, I would check the type of the given argument with `lua_type` and call the appropriate overload.

Comment: But the idea is a generic function to call any other generic functions and any number of arguments.

Comment: In a generic way, this is impossible.